# Route to a url in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-components

Hi I am new to angular 2 so please bear with me on this.

Situation: What I want to do is I want to navigate to a home page from Login page.
The home page will be a new page completely(which will act as a master page ant login page not).

But what happening is when I try to route to home it gives me an error with message:'Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent''. I am struggling on this how to resolve this issue

here is my app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'

const appRoutes:Routes=[
  {path:'App',component:AppComponent}, 
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent}
];



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{enableTracing:false}),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I haven't mentioned  anywhere because I am not including any child component or child view here. I want to redirect with whole new design which will further have child components.

My AppComponenet basically shows up the login page so after successfully logging in I want to redirect to HomeComponent with home.html

I hope I am clear on this. Help me on this guys. struggling here !!

Comment: We'll need to see the template as well. I suspect you are missing a [router outlet](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet).

Answer (score 1):

Add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your app.component i:e `[bootstrapped component]`.
This will act as a base page where all your components will load.

something like this

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-component',
      template: `
        <p>
          app-component works!
        </p>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Router Outlet on Index.html page . Load app component by default and then route to Home Component after success in code .